# jersey.api.MessageException message body writer and MIME media type text/xml not found

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jersey

The data is an object named "QueryResponse" which in turn owns a list of objects called "Todos".

I get this error:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message  body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<de.vogella.jersey.todo.model.Todo>, and MIME media type text/xml was not found
```

I have this jersey get method:

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public QueryResponse getTodos() {

 List todos = new ArrayList();
 todos.addAll(TodoDao.instance.getModel().values());
 return  new QueryResponse(todos);
}
```

And that's the QueryResponse object:

```
@XmlRootElement

public class QueryResponse {
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Todos")
@XmlElement(name = "Todo")
private List<Todo> todolist;
public QueryResponse(List<Todo> todolist)
{
    this.todolist = todolist;
}

public void setTodolist(List<Todo> todolist)
{
    this.todolist = todolist;
}
public List<Todo> getTodolist( )
{
    return this.todolist;
}
}
```

And this is the Todo class:

```
public class Todo
{


  private int id;
  private String summary;
  private String Description;

  public Todo()
 {
 }

  public Todo(int id, String summary)
 {
   this.id = id;
   this.summary = summary;
 }
 public int getId() {
   return this.id;
 }
 public void setId(int userID) {
   this.id = userID;
 }
 public String getSummary() {
   return this.summary;
 }
 public void setSummary(String summary) {
   this.summary = summary;
 }
 public String getDescription() {
   return this.Description;
 }
 public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.Description = description;
 }
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Annotate `public void getTodolist(List<Todo> todolist)` with the following annotation: `@XmlElementRef`
2. Annotate your QueryResponse with the following annotation: `@XmlSeeAlso({Todo.class})`

Comment: Annotate the Todo class with JAXB annotations.

Comment: i'm not sure what annotations should be present in the TODO, can you help me with that?

Comment: XmlRootElement
And remove the annotations you have from the XmlElement todolist member. (except for XmlElementRef)